# Visual relationship between javascript files in a project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ide

I'd like to be able to visually see the relationships of the files I require from every file in my project - that's because I'm using redux in my project, but there are probably cases where I introduced anti-pattern behaviour, by running code without dispatching an action creator first, and I'd love to visually check how complicated things are at this point.

Example: If A depends on B, and B depends on C, I'd love to visually see A with an arrow connected to B, with an arrow connected to C.

Is there any util, or IDE functionality to help me visualise my js code like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `madge` before: [npm link with install instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge). If you also install graphviz, you can export an svg of your dependencies with `madge --image graph.svg path/to/app.js`.

See example of one of my more modular repos!
 [image: example]